# What Open Source Software has Quality ASP.NET MVC C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, open-source

I am looking to read other peoples software to learn how to produce quality, speedy, reusable code. If the code has JQuery in it that would be great because I am learning JQuery as well. Thanks

Comment: Speedy and reusable? Do you mean create reusable code in a speedy fashion? Or creating reusable and speedy code? The latter might take a long time to conceive.

Comment: I mean the code execution time most be decent. I have taken a look at umbraco. They have very good code but it is not MVC. They say they will convert to MVC but I can't wait that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at **SharpArquitecture** for a complete arquitecture reference With ASP.Net MVC and NHibernate, include an example project.
http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/:

> Focused on Domain Driven Design,
>   Loosely coupled, Preconfigured
>   Infrastructure, Open
>   Ended Presentation.

Another Complete Reference is the **BeerHouse CMS** from ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution book:
http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/

> Concept of Model View
>   Controller,Creating RESTful
>   URLs,Leveraging jQuery to make a lean
>   and scalable website that incorporates
>   AJAX, Using Membership & Profile
>   modules in the MVC Framework, 
>   Incorporating LINQ to SQL to generate
>   your data access layer , Use of inline
>   C# code inside of your markup

Answer (score 1):

I have found [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) to be a good place to start.

[This](http://www.tampadev.org/News/Details/ASPNETMVCSampleApplicationsOpenSourceExamplesTutorials) site has several examples.

Comment: Thats a good one but i need something a little more advanced

Comment: @Luke101. Advanced in what way? I have a few other suggestions, but I'll need a bit more detail on your requirements. Quality, speedy and reusable are a bit vague. I think NerdDinner is pretty high quality, it is speedy for what it does. Reusability is always subjective. If you gave more information about what you want to do with MVC it might help.

Answer (score 0):

sutekishop which you can download at http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/ is a very good example to learn asp.net MVC. I am going through the source code and found a lot to learn. I agree NerdDinner is a little bit basic thought it's a good starting example.

Answer (score 0):

The [Storefront](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/#MVCStorefrontStarterKit) tutorial is a more mature application than NerdDinner. I'd suggest looking into that.